# localhost/projectname redirects to www.localhost.com/projectname (laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4.2

I am working on a project developed with laravel 4.2 on ubuntu 14.04 with php 5.5.9 and apache2 ..it was working normally then i faced a strange problem which is when i type `localhost/projectname` the firefox browser redirects me to `www.localhost.com/projectname` with a message 'Server not found'. When I checked the apache log I found this message:

> [core:notice] [pid 1309] AH00051: child pid 7040 exit signal Segmentation fault >(11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

I reviewed all the related questions on stackoverflow, but all didn't help.
also note that all other projects are working fine except this one

Comment: Either you are missing the entry in your **hosts** file: 127.0.0.1 localhost - or your firefox browser has **cached** the redirect, thus use a different browser and/or clear the cache.

Comment: i tried chrome and it gives me: 
 This page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

also i cleared the cache and same problem.
also note that all other projects are working fine except this one

Comment: (I know this is a bit old) have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: @Nigel Ren yes i did

Comment: @Hamdy Yea then refer to my first suggestion in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @Xatenev i also did check my hosts file and 127.0.0.1 localhost already exist and the problem still there